# .htaccess redirection

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My domain is http://www.somename.com.

I want if an user type {path to website}/index.php, it should redirect him to {site name}

basically I want to remove that index.php from the URL.

and one more thing, it should work both for
{www.sitename}
{sitename}

any idea is greatly appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule should do it:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Redirect permanent /index.php /
```

Note: you generally don't want to have a site available on both www and www-less hostnames. Pick one, and have the other variant redirect to it. This will let search engines know for sure they're the same site and not split reputation between them.